# Check the status of binary number in python

Tags: python

Given two integer variables a and b, and a boolean variable flag. The task is to check the status and return accordingly.
Return True for the following cases:

Either a or b is non-negative and flag is false.
Both a and b are negative and flag is true.
Otherwise, return false.

Example:

Input:

```
a = 1
b = -1
flag = False
```

Output:

```
True
```

Explanation:
Since a and b are positive and
negative respectively and flag
is False, so return True.

My solution is :

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
flag = bool(input())
def check_status(a, b, flag):
    if a<=0  and b<=0 and flag==True:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
check_status(a,b, flag)
```

I am getting a runtime error

Comment: Can't reproduce. And if `flag` is `"False"` this should print `False`. By the way `int(a)%(-1)` doesn't necessarily mean `a` is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code :

```
a=input("") 
b=input("") 
flag = input("") 
def check_status(a, b, flag): 
   if int(a)%(-1)==0 and int(b)%(-1)==0 and flag=="True":  
      print('True')  
   else:  
      print('False') 

check_status(a,b, flag)
```

- You can directly take `int(input(" "))` it will be more convenient. no need to convert them into integers and booleans into the *if* conditions.
- and need to correct the conditions in your **if** statement because it does not correctly specify the cases.
- if you are using **'%'** with **-1**, it is not a correct way to check if the number is negative.

I'd suggest this code:

```
a = int(input("value of a:"))
b = int(input("value of b:"))
flag = input("flag(True/False):")

#convert flag to boolean
flag = flag.str.lower() == "true"

if (a >= 0 or b >= 0 ) and not flag:
   print(" True")
elif a < 0 and b < 0 and flag:
   print("True")
else :
   print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you want your input to be considered as an integer, you should use `a=int(input(""))`
Then when trying to know whether your integer is negative or not you can compare the value to 0 using `a<0` or `a<=0`

Using simple logical comparators you can make a fonction that tests what you want:

```py
a=int(input(""))
b=int(input(""))
flag = input("flag: ")

def check_status(a, b, flag):
    if (a>0 or b>0) and flag=="false":
        print('True')
    elif (a<0 and b<0) and flag=="true":
        print('True')
    else: 
        print('False')
        
check_status(a,b, flag)
```